# For ansible, How to set var/fact that can be used by other roles in one role

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible to do some operations works. And I have such a playbook

```
### a.yaml


--- 

- hosts: host_a
  user: root
  tasks: 
    - name: task1
      git: repo=1.git
      register: res
    - set_fact:
        to_cont: res|changed

    - name: task2
      script: /do/some/thing.sh
      when: to_cont

- hosts: host2
  user: root
  roles:
    - { role: web, when: to_cont }
```

As above, I just want the role web to run under some conditions, and I have tried the set_fact module, but it doesnt work.

So i want to know, if anyone has some advice about this?

Answer (score 0):

In task 1 you're already registering (thus changing) the variable `res`. There's no need to use `set_fact`.

Here if the git repo is checked out/cloned, the variable `res` is registered. Then the second task will be run.

```
- hosts: host_a
  user: root
  tasks: 
    - name: task1
      git: repo=1.git
      register: res

    - name: task2
      script: /do/some/thing.sh
      when: res.changed
```

If the git repository is already checked out, variable `res` will not be changed and the second task won't run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It actually works for controlling task2. But the key point for me is to control the role called `web` that will run on `host2`. And I will try the following:  1. create a file with the value as content  2. use `delegate_to: host_a` to read the file and get the value

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following method, not sure if there's better one.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  user: root
  tasks:
    - name: Update Code for Web Server
      git: 1.git
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        con_fact: "{{ result | changed }}"
    - name: Set Flag
      shell: "echo {{ con_fact }} > /tmp/an_dy.yaml"
    - name: Compress the code
      shell: /do/some/thing.sh
      when:  con_fact


- hosts: web
  user: root
  pre_tasks:
    - shell: "cat /tmp/an_dy.yaml"
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: con_fact
  roles:
    - { role: web, when: con_fact.stdout.find('True') != -1 }
```